# How do I energize a 12v relay coil using a 2N2222 bipolar transistor?

Tags: arduino, transistors, mosfet, relay

I'm relatively new to working with transistors, and I'm having some trouble getting this circuit to work.  I want to use an Arduino's I/O pins (5V out) to energize a 12V relay coil.  To do this, I'm powering the Arduino with 12 volts via the power port on the Arduino.  For my transistor circuit, I'm pulling from the Vin pin on the Arduinio, which is also 12V.

I cannot figure out how to make it so that flipping an i/o pin from 0v to 5v switches the transistor, this allowing 12v to go across the relay coil.

I know the equations for the operating regions and I'm assuming I'm trying to drive the transistor into active by having Vbe > 0.7V, but I don't really know how to set up the circuit to properly regulate this.

Comment: I am editing the question to point that the 2N2222 is not a MOSFET.

Comment: Sorry, I sometimes just call transistors MOSFET's kind of like calling tissues Kleenex.  I don't work with BJT's much in my electronics class. also, I may be wrong, but isn't it active region we want rather than saturation for BJTs?

Comment: Well engineering is a more exact science than careless use of words. Better get used to being more exacting.

Comment: If you use a BJT as a switch, which is what you're looking for, you must turn it ON to energize the relay. For BJTs this means to be driven heavily in their saturation region. Do not confuse that with the saturation region of MOSFETs, which is analogous to the active region of BJTs. The terminology may seem incoherent, but the concept of saturation is related to the physics of the device, not to the shape of their characteristic curves, so the meaning of "saturation" is different for BJTs and MOSFETs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has probably already been answered 100's of times. But here is maybe the 201'st time.

Use a circuit that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: [There](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/3202/7036).  Even the transistor is the same.   Haven't we got the *close→duplicate* option?

Comment: If it was closed the OP may never have learned that BJT's are not MOSFET's.

Comment: One can still have a discussion in the comments under a closed question.  Now I'm wondering whether to merge or to send it to [Arduino.SE](http://arduino.stackexchange.com) so that they have one like this too.

Comment: Jesus. I'm new to the stack exchange. I'm just looking for information.  I apologize for making you guys so upset over a repeat question.

Comment: @user2057387  We are not upset, and no apoloigy is required.  But...  First you ask a repeat question.  Then you confuse BJT with MOSFET.  Well...  Consider stepping up your game. ;)

Comment: I'm taking my first class ever on transistors right now.

Comment: 10K on the base might be a little high, depending on the transistor gain you might need a somewhat smaller resistor.

Comment: Depends on Iload but I tend to agree. NO harm in using a 1k series base resistor.