# LCD Delamination and Lamination Process

Tags: lcd, delamination

I have an iMac display (thin LCD) that has the glass broken yet the LCD is fully functional and another iMac display with LCD broken but glass undamaged.

I am wondering if there is any recommended process that can do carried out to remove LCD with broken glass display and do the same in donor LCD with undamaged glass and re-laminate the working LCD with undamaged glass?

[image]

Comment: It's sad that you have two devices with distinct faults, in such a way that the working parts of one could theoretically be reunited to the parts of other for building a working device, but, I don't see how it could be done. Those screens are assembled in such a way that you can't disassemble them to obtain still working parts. The glasses are so thin, the adhesives are so strong, that the disassembling procedure certainly will damage the parts.

Comment: This procedure, even if possible, would be a kludge, and, for this, I would only suggest to consult a third part repairer (I'm not talking of an Apple's authorized service; the only thing an authorized service would do is replace the part, or say that you need to buy a new device). Even if this proposed procedure is possible, it is complicated enough to be done only by a professional repairer.

Comment: @mguima, hey this is the kind of response I was looking for! thanks a lot! Actually I purchased the broken glass display (I was able to get it cheaply due to broken glass) as a replacement of my original display that has the LCD problem as shown in the image. So I wondered if instead of discarding my original display I could use its perfectly intact glass and replace it with the purchased LCD with broken glass to have a decent replacement.

Comment: @mguima Alright I shall try to find the professional repairer to see if he can salvage the glass out of my original LCD, if it breaks then no issues as it has no use for me, but say if the glass gets salvaged then I am left with only one concern i.e, the replacement part that I got cheaply has broken glass on the corners and a crack line, salvaging the LCD by removing broken glass/glue could be a nightmare and might destroy the LCD in the process. Right?

Answer (score 2):

I dont think it can be done, only very skilled person can get it done to cut apart the lamination using the blade without breaking the glass. Again it requires skills and patience and slight heating of the LCD panel to loosen the glue, which could destroy your host LCD with broken glass.